# Store variable value in each PLC cycle

Tags: plc, st

Is it possible to store a variable value in each PLC cycle? I need the first 10 values each time to perform some calculations. I am using the OpenPCS platform and ST for programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of values and then store as array values

```
VAR
    aBuffer : ARRAY[1..32] OF WORD;
    init:BOOL; (* Init array *)
    rest:BOOL; (*  Reset *)
    val:WORD; (*  Value *)
    iCount:INT; (* Array index *)
END_VAR
VAR_TEMP
    iTmp : INT;
END_VAR

iTmp := UINT_TO_INT(N) - 1;

IF NOT init OR rest THEN
    init := TRUE;
    FOR iCount := 1 TO iTmp DO
        aBuffer[iCount] := val;
    END_FOR;
END_IF

iCount := INC1(iCount, 32);
aBuffer[iCount] := val;
```

This is a code example that created 32 elements array and every new PLC cycle assign new element and rotates.

After that, you can calculate the average or min and max.

INC1 increments given value by one until it reaches 32 and then reset to 1.

Comment: Hi @Sergey Romanov! Thank you for quick help. I have a problem declaring **VAR_TEMP** even though I am using separate FB.

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be temp. You can declare it in VAR scope.